# Facebook Embedded Post: force mobile view

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, mobile, user-agent

i've created a web platform where you can insert 'facebook embedded posts'.

[Facebook Embedded Posts Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts)

As you can see, i can show a post on my pages simply with

```
<div class="fb-post" data-href="{your-post-url}"></div>
```

With this tag, you can show a post in Desktop version: from 350px to 750px width.

The mobile view will be used automatically only on mobile devices. Docs says: "On mobile web, Embedded Posts automatically scale to the width of the container."

The problem is that i'd like to show these posts in their mobile version also on desktop view.

I've tried changing the browser's user agent, but probably i'm doing something wrong. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: No, that is not supported, the docs also state that this will be done automatically vs. being an option of the plugin.

Comment: Yeah i've seen thanks.. but.. wait a second.. you're the same Bjorn Kaiser working for Facebook? Working at the 'submission' bug of some hours ago? If you're the person well, probably we're linked by fate! O.o (i'll explain you)