# Contain Facebook embedded post inside parent container

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've got a simple four-column card layout (Bootstrap grid), which collapses to a single-column layout on mobile. I want to embed a Facebook post within one of the cards. The problem is that Facebook embedded posts on desktop don't expand/collapse to fill their parent container, as they do on mobile. What I'd like to know is if there is a way around this. My cards are about 270px wide, which is below the 350px minimum width for desktop, according to [their docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts).

My container is a simple div like so:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="fb-post" data-href="{{post.facebook_link}}">
        <!-- Here is what the embedded post's structure looks like -->
        <span>
            <iframe>
                <!-- Widget lives in here -->
            </iframe>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Right now when I embed a post in one of my cards, the post forces the card to expand, which wrecks my layout (see attachment). I'm looking for a way to force the post to fill the parent container either through a CSS/JS solution or tricking the Facebook SDK to thinking that it's on mobile.

I've only come across [one other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225973/facebook-embedded-post-force-mobile-view) on this issue, but that person explicitly wanted the mobile version of the post. In my case I don't care if it's the mobile version or desktop version as long as I can get it to fill the parent container. For that reason, *this question is **not** a duplicate*.

So far I've tried manipulating the height/width of the iframe and/or its parent `span` element, but as soon as I adjust those numbers, the changes are undone, since the SDK is setting them dynamically.

[image]

Comment: You can’t manipulate any CSS inside the iframe, since it is from another domain. And tricking the SDK into thinking the device was a mobile one will likely not succeed either, because AFAIK uses User-Agent sniffing as the main means to decide whether a device is “mobile” or not.

Answer (score 0):

One way around this is that worked for me, was to use hidden and visible divs using bootstrap 3 css and adjust data-width in facebook code to suit the container size. I used this on my website here [link to page](http://ddry.co.uk/contact_us.html) if you want a live example. I understand your using iframe, but this was the only option I could find for my site. I have provided my code here just as a guide to illustrate my point, however you will be able to style it better than me as I a sloppy coder I'm afraid...

https://jsfiddle.net/andydry1/6t5o2n8z/1/

```
data-adapt-container-width="true" *make sure this is set to true*

data-width="300" *change width to suit extra-small, small and large divs *
```

This isn't the exact answer for your situation; However it may provide some help :-)